# Prove that for all integers $n$, if $n − 3$ is divisible by $4$ then $ n^2 − 1$ is divisible by $8.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I think I know how to prove that once $n$ is odd, then $n^2 -1$ is divisible by $8$ but I am unsure of how to show the steps of when $n - 3$ is divisible by $4$ it is also odd... I am simply very confused. Thank you

Comment: try to use induction. base case 1, then do the inductive step

Comment: If $n-3$ is divisible by $4$, then $n-3$ is even, $n-2$ is odd, $n-1$ is even, and $n$ is odd.

Comment: *Hint:* if $n-3$ is divisible by $4$, then $n = 3 + 4k$ for some $k$. What do you get if you square this expression and consider it mod $8$?

Comment: $n$ is plainly odd. It is well known that the square of any odd number is $\equiv 1 \bmod 8$

Answer (score 3):

If $n-3$ is divisible by $4$, then $n+3$ is divisible by $2$

($4|n-3\implies 2|n-3\implies 2|n-3+6=n+3$),

so $(n-3)(n+3)=n^2-9$ is divisible by $8$,

so $n^2-9+8=n^2-1$ is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n-3$ is divisible by $4$, i.e. $n \equiv 3 \mod 4$, then $n \equiv 3$ or $7 \mod 8$,
and $n^2 \equiv 3^2 \equiv 1$ or $7^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$.

Alternatively,  "$n-3$ is divisible by $4$" means $n = 3 + 4 k$ for some integer $k$, and then $n^2 - 1 = (3+4k)^2 - 1 = 8 + 24 k + 16 k^2 = 8 (1 + 3 k + 2 k^2)$ is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use induction. But also, notice that if $n-3$ is divisible by $4$ then $n+1$ is also divisible by $4$ and $n-1$ is divisible by $2$. Finally, we know $n^2+1 = (n+1)(n-1) = 4k*(4k-2) = 16k^2-8k = 8(2k^2-1)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

If $n-3$ is divisible by 4, then $n-3=4x$ for some integer $x$. Solve for $n$ and you get $n=4x+3$. Go ahead and square $n$ and take away 1. You should see right away that this polynomial is always divisible by 8.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.

$4| n-3$ so there is and integer $k$ so that $n-3 =4k$ so $n = 4k+3$.

So $n^2 -1 = (4k+3)^2 -1= (16k^2 + 24k + 9)-1 = 16k^2 + 24k + 8 = 8(2k^2 + 3k + 1)$.

That's all.

Comment: Excuse me, but you answered 3 hours after Robert and basically repeated his alternative solution. Why?